# Notepad++ regex to match and replace first comma between certain tags

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have data like so opened in Notepad++:

```
<title>Name 1, Address 1, NY</address>
<title>Name 2, Address 2, California</address>
<title>Name 3, Address 3, Texas</address>
<title>Name 4</title> <address>Address 4, Utah</address> <-- this line is 100% correct
```

...and I would llike to target the first comma on the groups that need proper tag enclosing, and replace it by: `</title><address>`

I did this and it targets the second group (address), but the *replace* regex I don't know what to use to keep the integrity of the address data, I tried something like this but it destroys the whole address:

- Find What: `, (.+address)`
- Replace with: `</title><address>(.+address)`

How to simply replace the *first* comma by new tags `</title><address>`?

Comment: To keep the captured part after the replacement, use the backreference to that group, in your case, it is `\1` (or `$1`). Do not use regex in replacement patterns, they are specific template strings.

Comment: Awesome I made it like so and it works: </title><address>\1 Thanks!

Comment: How to avoid targeting the already enclosed title tags?

Comment: Try `<title>[^<>,\v]*\K,\h*([^<>\v]*</address)` and replace with `</title> <address>\1`. But in this case, your requirement - *How to simply replace the first comma by new tags* - is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```php
<title>[^<>,\v]*\K,\h*([^<>\v]*</address>)
```

Replace with `</title> <address>\1`.

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4plyaK/2).

*Details*

- `<title>` - a string `<title>`
- `[^<>,\v]*` - zero or more chars other than `<`, `>`, comma and any vertical whitespace
- `\K` - match reset operator that disacards all text matched so far
- `,` - a comma
- `\h*` - zero or more horizontal whitespaces
- `([^<>\v]*</address>)` - Group 1 (the `$1` or `\1` backreference refers to the group value):

  - `[^<>\v]*` - zero or more chars other than `<`, `>` and any vertical whitespace
  - `</address>` - a `</address>` string.

Comment: I would use a short code  Find: `^.*?\K,`  Replace all with `</title> <address>`

Comment: @HajiRahmatullah You must be thinking of the "replace the first comma" solution, as stated in the question. I closed the question as a duplicate when I also was tricked by this requirement. However, the problem is not that simple, the comma *must* be inside the two non-matching tags, `<title>` and `</address>`. This becomes clear after trying out the [regex you suggest](https://regex101.com/r/4plyaK/3): 1) the spacing becomes a bit messy and 2) the wrong `,` gets replaced on the last line making the result invalid.

Comment: Yes I saw it effects the last line, but the last line is an assumption he is indicating his output to be like this... and you see he has misspelled the word title as `tile ` ?  on the fourth line